# Adding middleware to bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, middleware

I am trying to add middleware into echo bot, that converts message into lower cases.

I have created Middleware class that inherits from IMiddleware

```
public class MiddlewareOne : IMiddleware
    {
        public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            if(turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(turnContext.Activity.Text);

                turnContext.Activity.Text = turnContext.Activity.Text.ToLower();
                await next(cancellationToken);

                Debug.WriteLine(turnContext.Activity.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                await next(cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to add it into Startup.cs file. I found somewhere it should be added as Transient.

```
services.AddTransient<MiddlewareOne>();
```

Still, it's not working. I think MiddlewareOne class is okay, but how should I configure it in Startup.cs file?

Thank you

Comment: I have found that the adapter supports only 2 middleware via Use(). If you try to Use() a third middleware it gets ignored. Have you noticed this or know of a solution to add more than 2 middleware to the pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to register the middleware in your BotFrameworkAdapter descendant (e.g. BotFrameworkHttpAdapter) by calling the [Use method in constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.botframeworkadapter.use?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_BotFrameworkAdapter_Use_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_IMiddleware_). You can pass the middleware as a constructor parameter and DI will take care of activation.

An example (made without VS assistance)

```
public class MyAdapter : BotFrameworkHttpAdapter
{
    public MyAdapter(MiddlewareOne mw1, IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<BotFrameworkHttpAdapter> logger)
        : base(configuration, logger)
    {
        Use(mw1);
        // other code..
    }
}
```

Comment: I have found that the adapter supports only 2 middleware via Use(). If you try to Use() a third middleware it gets ignored. Have you noticed this or know of a solution to add more than 2 middleware to the pipeline?

Comment: Are you sure that the second middleware calls the next delegate in the `OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())` method implementation?

Comment: Thanks. You are right, I double-checked one of the middleware classes and it had a condition to skip calling next(), which was causing the problem. Thanks for the quick reply and help.